# Selecting latest values based on column from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which has data as:

```
    SymbolTime  AsdRtg MaturityDate
0   2019-10-18  1.9500   2020-05-01
1   2019-10-19  1.9820   2020-05-01
2   2019-10-20  2.1075   2020-05-01
3   2019-10-18  2.1075   2020-08-01
4   2019-10-19  1.7790   2020-08-01
```

I want to extract data from above so that only rows which has the latest `SymbolTime` date is returned. i.e. desired output is:

```
    SymbolTime  AsdRtg MaturityDate
2   2019-10-20  2.1075   2020-05-01
4   2019-10-19  1.7790   2020-08-01
```

I think I need to use `groupby` in some ways but I am not able to put it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [pd.Dataframe.nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) from series

```
df.loc[df.SymbolTime.nlargest(2).index]
```

**Edit**

```
df.loc[df.sort_values('MaturityDate',ascending=False)['SymbolTime'].nlargest(2).index]
```

Out:

```
SymbolTime  AsdRtg  MaturityDate
2   2019-10-20  2.1075  2020-05-01
4   2019-10-19  1.7790  2020-08-01
```

Comment: Funnily enough, your output does not match the expected output

Comment: nice Observation @rafaelc, incorporated the change to OPs output :)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, `groupby` and `tail`

```
df.SymbolTime = pd.to_datetime(df.SymbolTime)

df.groupby(df.SymbolTime.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()).tail(1)
```

---

```
  SymbolTime  AsdRtg MaturityDate
2 2019-10-20  2.1075   2020-05-01
4 2019-10-19  1.7790   2020-08-01
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`

```
(df.sort_values('SymbolTime')    # your data appears to be sorted by SymbolTime, so you can drop this
   .drop_duplicates('MaturityDate',keep='last')
)
```

Output:

```
   SymbolTime  AsdRtg MaturityDate
4  2019-10-19  1.7790   2020-08-01
2  2019-10-20  2.1075   2020-05-01
```